# React Js Firebase Cloud messaging not recieving notifications when screen is active

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

So this is my index file

```js
import * as firebase from "firebase";

firebaseConfig = {
     apiKey: "x",
     authDomain: "x",
     databaseURL: "x",
     projectId: "x",
     storageBucket: "x",
     messagingSenderId: "x",
     appId: "x"
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const messaging = firebase.messaging();

Notification.requestPermission().then((permission) => {
  if (permission === 'granted') {
    console.log('Notification permission granted.');
    return messaging.getToken().then(function (token)
    {
        console.log(token, 'firebase token generated here');
        localStorage.setItem('fcmToken', token);
    })
  } else {
    console.log('Unable to get permission to notify.');
  }
});

messaging.onMessage((payload) => {
    console.log('Message received. ', payload);
  });

const googleAuthProvider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

export { firebase, googleAuthProvider };
```

and this is my firebase-messaging-sw.js file

```js
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.5.0/firebase-messaging.js');

firebase.initializeApp({
    messagingSenderId: "x",
});

const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {

     console.log(payload);
     console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
     // Customize notification here
      const notificationTitle = payload.data.title;
      const notificationOptions = {
        body: payload.data.body,
        icon: '/xxx.png'
      };

      return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
        notificationOptions);
});
```

I am trying to send notification from the postman.
When the tab is not active. The notification appears. And even the firebase-messaging-sw.js catches the console.log
But when the tab is active

```js
messaging.onMessage((payload) => {
    console.log('Message received. ', payload);
});
```

this is not triggered in the index.js

This is the payload I am trying to send.

```html
{
 "to" : "x",
 "notification" : {
 "body" : "great match!!!!!!!!",
 "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!1",
 "content_available" : true,
 "priority" : "high",
 },
 "data" : {
 "body" : "great match..............",
 "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark..............",
 "content_available" : true,
 "priority" : "high",
 }
}
```

I even tried payload with different combinations

```html
{
 "to" : "x",
 "notification" : {
 "body" : "great match!!!!!!!!",
 "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!1",
 "content_available" : true,
 "priority" : "high",
 },
}
```

and also like

```html
{
 "to" : "x",
 "data" : {
 "body" : "great match..............",
 "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark..............",
 "content_available" : true,
 "priority" : "high",
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so finally found answer to this.
I don't think it's a direct fix but it's a workaround.

```js
navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener("message", (message) => {
    console.log(message);
});
```